# Magento2 checkout page changes

Tags: magento2, checkout

Can any one help me how to edit the checkout page street address label in magento2.

Comment: You can translate by adding to i18n Csv

Comment: ok i will try it , get back to you,

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, you can change the label.

The first way is use [translation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html) at theme level and it is the Best way.

> `app/design/frontend/{Themevendorname}/{ThemeName}/i18n/`

That changes will reflect all over you're the current theme.Like customer address page at My account Section etc.

Create `{Langauecode}.csv` if it does not exist at there

and add  the text

```
"Street Address","Road Address"
```

Then do static content deploy to apply the translation.

Second-way, to use [Plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

**Create a plugin for the class**

> Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor

Create after method `afterProcess()`  on  `process()` and change the label. This way the label only change at the checkout page. not all over the theme.

**Plugin class:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by Amit Bera.
 * User: Amit Kumar Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 */

namespace StackExchange\Works\Plugin;


class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    public function afterprocess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    )
    {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'])) {
            $fields = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'];

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['label']
                ='my label';
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!--
    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225561/magento2-checkout-page-changes
    -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="magento-checkout-page-changes" type="StackExchange\Works\Plugin\LayoutProcessorPlugin" />
    </type>

</config>
```

Comment: perfect... Its working as expected.